# Remote XML file is poorly written causing parsing errors

Tags: php, xml, xml-parsing, rss, html-parsing

I am writing an RSS type reader webpage to parse information from some game websites.

One of the games RSS feed is poorly written.

They did not bother wrapping the description into CDATA and it is giving errors using simplexml_load_file to parse.

Here is the function I wrote to parse it:

```
 function displayAll($url) {

 $url = "https://www.game.com/newsfeed/rss.vm";
 $game = simplexml_load_file($url);

 $item = $game->rss->channel->item;
 foreach ($item as $items) {

 echo '<li>';
 echo ''.$items->title.'';
 echo ''.$items->description.'';
 echo ''.$items->link.'';
 echo '</li>';

  }
 }
```

I am getting the following errors:

```
 Warning: simplexml_load_file() [function.simplexml-load-file]: https://www.game.com/newsfeed/rss.xml:15: parser error : 
 Entity 'nbsp' not defined in /results.php on line 27
 Warning: simplexml_load_file() [function.simplexml-load-file]: https://www.game.com/newsfeed/rss.xml:20: parser error : 
 Entity 'nbsp' not defined in /results.php on line 27
```

Getting multiple of the same error all revolving around the html poorly written in the feed.

I am asking for how to resolve this, is there a way to convert the html back to letters/spaces/etc tags in the description of the xml before it is parsed?

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: You could try doing some regex and replacements on the stuff you know breaks simple xml before passing it into simplexml so pull it back with a curl and store it as a local var and process it then after that pass it into simplexml its a swine but its the rule rather than the exception with most xml feeds from other places very few (even from large tech sites who should know better!) are correctly formatted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
$data = file_get_contents($url);
$data = str_replace(array('<description>','</description>'), array('<description><![CDATA[',']]></description>'), $data);

$game = simplexml_load_string($data);
```

Comment: That worked! Didn't think to try replacing the description tag.